VB6 ADODB Recordset displays Chinese characters as?
I am working on modifying existing code that is written in VB6. This code is written to fetch the Chinese and English data from database[SQL Server 2016] and to show in crystal report.
The table in SQL server has chinese as well as English data and when I query it in SQL query window it shows the data correctly for both the languages. However when I try to get same data through VB6 it gives me the ???? for Chinese data in Recordset.
here is my code that I uses to fetch the data:
strSQL = "select LblValue from Language.dbo.tempLbls"

Set m_rstempLbls = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
m_rstempLbls.Open strSQL, m_Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

If !m_rstempLbls.EOF Then
   TransalatedValue = m_rstempLbls!LblValue 'This line displays the ???? for Chinese characters
End If

In above code  m_rstempLbls!LblValue displays the ???? for Chinese characters.
Am I doing anything wrong here? Should I read the Chinese value differently? Any lead would be of much help.
Thanks in advance

That only happens if you try to read or display text using the wrong codepage. VB6 strings are Unicode, nvarchar fields in SQL Server are Unicode, so unless the strings were stored in varchar fields, the problem is in Crystal Reports. What version are you using? What's the report's language or codepage?

Considering this is VB6, which reached end of support 16 years ago, are you also running this application on a ancient device as well? Could you being using a font that doesn't support the characters or (because it's such an old version of Windows) doesn't have a Chinese language pack, and it can't be installed?

VB6 is still supported, even though the last version was released in 2008. That's not the problem. An ancient Crystal Reports version, with the wrong locale, will mangle text

You say you're modifying the code, has it ever worked? And where are you displaying the characters? If you're on some label, the problem might be in the labels, not the fetching itself

@PanagiotisKanavos The code always has worked fine. however When I modified it in my dev environment[Windows 10 enterprise] this gives issue even before it reaches to Crystal report. when I debug the code the value in recordset shows ?? [n my case m_rstempLbls!LblValue]

No, the issue is in Crystal Reports. You must be using a very old version that uses the user's (ie your's) locale to display text. If you set your system codepage to UTF8, an old Crystal Reports version will choke and try to display each byte as a character. UTF8 wasn't available as a system codepage until after the first Windows 10 release and is still considered a Beta feature, precisely because old software wouldn't be able to handle this.
Windows uses Unicode natively since the very first Windows NT version back 1994. VB6 strings are Unicode too. OLE only allows Unicode strings

Well, what did you change from when it worked 'til it didn't?

BTW the code you posted has issues too. There's no reason to use CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") in VB6, only in VBScript. In VB6 you can use New ADODB.Connection or New ADODB.Recordset. Check Creating and executing a simple command in the docs

On the other hand, back in the 1990s-2000s Unicode meant the 2-byte UCS-2 subset that couldn't handle Chinese characters, which require 2 or 4 bytes. Assuming the text was stored in an nvarchar field, Crystal Reports may not be able to display it even as Unicode.

@Disha5 VB6 immediate window and cursor bubble showing current variable value are not suitable for inspecting string variables that contain non western characters. Exporting your recordset to some UTF8 file (using ADODB Stream) might help.

@PanagiotisKanavos I uses SAP crystal Report for Visual studio.

@siggemannen I have added a method to create a temporary table to insert value of "TransalatedValue" that I receive from above mentioned code snippet.

Well, maybe the temp table uses varchar instead of nvarchar. You leave too little info for anyone to help you. If that was the only change that is

@siggemannen Temp table uses NVARCHAR

@PanagiotisKanavos I changed my code to use New ADODB.Recordset but still issue persist.

And the original table used nvarchar too? i dunno, you should check: exec sp_help  and see if it uses some custom collation

@siggemannen Yes, original table has used NVARCHAR as well. Also before I edit the VB6 component[of which above code is part of] were working fine

Did you compare the collations?

@siggemannen, I have used SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation

UNICODE support in Crystal Reports started with version 9.
Perhaps you are on an older version.
